# Run shell script command with user iteration

Tags: xcode, applescript-objc

I want to execute a shell command in an Applescript application, but this command asks for a user confirmation ie: "Do you want to proceed with this operation and y/n?"
I want the answer to be yes, could someone give me an example of how to do this?

Comment: If your script reads from stdin, you should be able to run "yes | yourscript.sh"

Comment: Thanks, @Gereon,working like a charm!